# find rows from a dataframe after gropuby and with max size value in python

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i have a dataframe like

```
 cust   fruit
  A     MANGO
  A     APPLE
  A     MANGO
  A     APPLE
  A     MANGO
  B     MANGO
  B     APPLE
  B     APPLE
  B     APPLE
  B     MANGO
```

i need a result which will contain max count of their groupby result and find that group and reanme the column to cust FAV_FRUIT.

```
cust  FAV_FRUIT
  A    MANGO
  B    APPLE
```

what i am doing is

```
df = df.groupby(['cust','fruit']).size()
```

df become a series and with a index cust and fruit and a column 0 which contain the size values.

how to select those groups with max size and rename that column with suffix FAV_.
please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to add a column using `groupby` and `transform` to flag which fruit is the most popular, you can then filter the df:

```
In [160]:
df['FAV_FRUIT'] = df.groupby('cust')['fruit'].transform(lambda x: x == x.value_counts().index[0])
df

Out[160]:
  cust  fruit FAV_FRUIT
0    A  MANGO      True
1    A  APPLE     False
2    A  MANGO      True
3    A  APPLE     False
4    A  MANGO      True
5    B  MANGO     False
6    B  APPLE      True
7    B  APPLE      True
8    B  APPLE      True
9    B  MANGO     False

In [161]:
df.loc[df['FAV_FRUIT']==True].drop_duplicates()

Out[161]:
  cust  fruit FAV_FRUIT
0    A  MANGO      True
6    B  APPLE      True
```

You can overwrite the boolean values:

```
In [164]:
df.loc[df['FAV_FRUIT']==True, 'FAV_FRUIT'] = df['fruit']
df[df['FAV_FRUIT']!=False].drop_duplicates()

Out[164]:
  cust  fruit FAV_FRUIT
0    A  MANGO     MANGO
6    B  APPLE     APPLE
```

Comment: @Edchum-appreciate your help.But i want to add that fruit name into that FAV_FRUIT field and that not by df["FAV_FRUIT"] = df['fruit']